# System shuts down when training ml models

Tags: nvidia, ssh, python, cuda, visual-studio-code

I have a system with 4xRTX2080 used primarily for ml model training.

```
Nvidia driver version: 430.26
CUDA Version: 10.2
```

I use VSCode's remote development extension to remote into the machine and start the training. The GPU usage is usually higher than 70% on all 4 GPUs when training.

If I leave the system like this for ~12 hours the ssh connection will break, the computer will go offline, but the pc won't power off. If I hook up a keyboard and a monitor to it, there is no output signal to the monitor, and the pc doesn't react to the keyboard input.

It's very important for me to be able to leave the training for longer periods of time without worrying that the computer will turn off.

How do I even begin to debug this?

Comment: This sounds like the system is hard locking maybe due to heat or under power of the system.  Does the computer feel really hot when it locks up like this?  Do you have sufficient power going to all 4 video cards?  According to the requirements one card requires at least 650W PS.  Maybe try with 1 or 2 cards at first to try to determine if it is a hardware issue with the system.

Comment: The highest temperatures I've seen were ~85C . The power supply is 1500W total, and the cards report 225W TDP. I think the vendor stress tested the cards before shipping the unit, but now that you mention it, the 1500W seems pretty close to the limit.